# How to define and print a variable value at the same time in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am facing issue in one bash script as I have print the value of a variable and after then using that variable as an input to another variable but values are not getting print as I understand I have assign value to a variable and then can print.
So I want to know can I define and print a variable value at the same time and store the value to use in another variable within the scope of the function.

For ex.

```
a="My name is Vikas"  
echo "a=My name is Vikas"  
b="${a} Singh"  
echo "b=${a} Singh"
```

but I want to do the below

```
echo "a=My name is Vikas"  
echo "b=${a} Singh"
```

so output should be like

```
a=My name is Vikas  
b=My name is Vikas Singh.
```

Please help

Comment: You don't do that at the same time, but in sequence. Please read [Bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/). Perhaps you want to define your shell function?

Comment: BTW, why don't you code `echo "a=$a"` in your second line? Your question remains unclear. Consider starting your script with `#!/bin/bash -vx` during the debugging phase.

Comment: Yes, i forgot to add this echo "a=$a" here but in my script yes I'm using - echo "a=$a" and echo "b=$b".

Comment: Still unclear question; please read the [documentation of `bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/) then provide a [MCVE]; feel free to improve your question (e.g. look for appropriate words in a dictionary, if you are, like me, a non-native English speaker).

Comment: Hello,
its just like if I don't define a variable value but I'm just printing that variable and its value in file so is there any way where I can use that variable as an input to other variable.

Comment: Please **edit your question** to improve it, and provide some [MCVE]. Avoid commenting your own question (which is still unclear). Take time to read the documentation. Perhaps you want to use [printf(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/printf.1.html) and [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)

Comment: I think that you want to do is not possible in bash, because assignment does not return the assigned value (like for instance in C). Instead, in bash any command returns an exit status: 0 for success and a value greater than 0 for failure.

Comment: Maybe you need to use some sophisticated kind of [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

Answer (score 4):

an assignment can be done while doing an expansion in the case variables are not already set

```
a= b=
echo "a=${a:=My name is Vikas}"
echo "b=${b:=${a} Singh}"
```

[from manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

> ${parameter:=word}
>   If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is assigned to parameter. The value of parameter is then substituted. Positional parameters and special parameters may not be assigned to in this way.

a time later, I realized that this could be misleading : it is `echo "a=.."` which is doing assignment but expansion, which made me understand the question differently, assignments (like any other commands) can be traced with `set -x` or `set -o xtrace` (to undo `set +x` or `set +o xtrace`) (another similar option `set -v` or `set -o verbose` show the command before expansion)

```
set -x
a="My name is Vikas"  
b="${a} Singh"
set +x
```

will write assignments after expansion to (file descriptor 2) standard error.

Comment: There I go stating that something is impossible and a minute later I'm proven wrong :D

Comment: Note that there is no real use case `${parameter:-word}` is sufficient for defaulting, and simple assigment is shorter

Comment: I just  realized that `echo "a=..."` could be misleading, and made me understand question differently,maybe you wanted to trace an assignment, updating my answer

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly print the contents of a variable into another variable. The command to print is `printf`, and the option `-v` prints to a variable. From the man page:

```
   printf [-v var] format [arguments]
          Write the formatted arguments to the standard output under the control of
          the format.  The -v option causes the output to be assigned to  the  vari-
          able var rather than being printed to the standard output.
```

So...

```
$ fname="Vikas"; lname="Singh"
$ printf -v a 'My name is %s' "$fname"
$ printf -v b '%s %s' "$a" "$lname"
$ printf '%s\n%s\n' "$a" "$b"
My name is Vikas
My name is Vikas Singh
```

But if you want your output to include the variable names, you should probably use `declare -p`:

```
$ declare -p a b
declare -- a="My name is Vikas"
declare -- b="My name is Vikas Singh"
```

By using `declare -p`, your output may be recycled as input to recreate the same variables in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I think you were trying to do something like this.

```
b="${a='My name is Vikas'} Singh"
echo $a
echo $b
```

The command within curly braces `{` and `}` sets the variable `a` in the current shell, and the outer assigment sets `b`.

[Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html)

EDIT: Actually, as Nauhel pointed out, the variables should not be set. So it should begin with `unset a`.